# How to select an annotaion and pass an id to specific detail page?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, mapkit

I added beepid as string in myannotation class custom and this is rest :

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    DLog(@"calloutAccessoryControlTapped");

    /// detail page opening but beeid not passing

    MyAnnotation *myAnnot = (MyAnnotation *)view.annotation;





    BeepsDetail *objCont = [[BeepsDetail alloc] initWithNibName:@"BeepsDetail" bundle:nil];
    objCont.mId = myAnnot.beepid;
    objCont.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController: objCont animated: YES];

    //[paramDic setValue:[mObject.mDic objectForKey:@"beepid"] forKey:@"beepid"];
    [objCont release];


}
```

Comment: error is at NSMutableDictionary *dic = [placeName objectAtIndex:MKAnnotationView.annotion]; for annotation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [placeName objectAtIndex:MKAnnotationView.annotion];
```

gives an error because `MKAnnotationView` is the *class* and there is no `annotation` method in the class.  What you would use is `view.annotation` since `view` is the instance of the `MKAnnotationView` that was selected.  Also, `annotion` is spelled wrong.

However, that still won't work because `view.annotation` is the annotation object and not the integer index into your `placeName` array.

You say you are "clicking on the right arrow" which implies the right callout accessory button in the callout (and not the annotation itself).  In that case, you should be detecting the select using the `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` delegate method instead of `didSelectAnnotationView`.

In both cases, you would first get access to the annotation object using `view.annotation` and then using some property (possibly custom) of the annotation object, determine the detail data.

For example, if you have created a custom `MKAnnotation` class (instead of using `MKPointAnnotation`), you could add the `beepId` property to it, set it when creating the annotation and in the delegate method you could retrieve it like this:

```
MyAnnotationClass *myAnnot = (MyAnnotationClass *)view.annotation;
objCont.mId = myAnnot.beepid;
```